# Why is the alert returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is the alert returning undefined or blank even though the ID exists and has a value?

```
 $('#tblData > tbody > tr').each(function() {                                                                                                         

              $(this).children('td').each(function(){

                  ID = $(this).children().first().next().attr("id");
                  alert(ID);

                });                          
                count = count + 1;                    
           });
```

New row

```
   $("#tblData tbody").append(
            "<tr>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_Room_No'>Room No</label><select single='single' size='1' name='BookingRoom["+id+"][roomId]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_roomId'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_startDate' class='required'>Start Date <span class='required'>*</span></label><input name='BookingRoom["+id+"][startDate]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_startDate' type='text' /></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_endDate' class='required'>End Date <span class='required'>*</span></label><input name='BookingRoom["+id+"][endDate]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_endDate' type='text'  /></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_adults' class='required'>Adults <span class='required'>*</span></label><select single='single' size='5' name='BookingRoom["+id+"][adults]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_adults'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_children' class='required'>Children <span class='required'>*</span></label><select single='single' size='5' name='BookingRoom["+id+"][children]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_children'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></td>"+
            "<td><button type='button'>Delete</button></td>"+
            "</tr>");
```

Comment: Probably because the elements you are trying to select haven't been created yet.

Comment: Do some debugging. Either insert a `debugger` statement where you have `alert`, or use a couple `console.log`s to make sure your actually selecting the right elements, that you loop is actually executing, etc. These are the first steps you should take before posting a question here.

Comment: There's an add new row button on the page that appends to the DOM. Does the page have to be reloaded before the elements are created?

Comment: Use Chrome or Firefox Developer tools, they come with built in debugging feature, set breakpoints and examine the values of your variables. You are better of with a proper debugging tool on the long run, than relying on alert();

Comment: If he did it before the elements existed, the row wouldn't exist, and therefore the alert would never be reached... unless there was an existing row of course

Answer (score 0):

The alert is returning undefined because your variable "ID" is undefined.  It does not exist and does not have a value.

This is not to be contradictory, but rather to point out that your assumptions are obviously incorrect, because the output does not lie.  ID really is undefined.

This JSFiddle seems to indicate that the (extremely spare) code you provide does display an ID for every element except the submit button, to which you do not apply an ID.

[JSFiddle with your code in it](http://jsfiddle.net/jptillman/hrptf/)

```
<table id="tblData">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>

var id = 1; 

$("#tblData tbody").append(
            "<tr>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_Room_No'>Room No</label><select single='single' size='1' name='BookingRoom["+id+"][roomId]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_roomId'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_startDate' class='required'>Start Date <span class='required'>*</span></label><input name='BookingRoom["+id+"][startDate]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_startDate' type='text' /></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_endDate' class='required'>End Date <span class='required'>*</span></label><input name='BookingRoom["+id+"][endDate]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_endDate' type='text'  /></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_adults' class='required'>Adults <span class='required'>*</span></label><select single='single' size='5' name='BookingRoom["+id+"][adults]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_adults'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_"+id+"_children' class='required'>Children <span class='required'>*</span></label><select single='single' size='5' name='BookingRoom["+id+"][children]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_children'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></td>"+
            "<td><button type='button'>Delete</button></td>"+
            "</tr>");

$('#tblData > tbody > tr').each(function() {                                                                                                         
                console.log($(this).html());
              $(this).children('td').each(function(){
                 console.log($(this).html());
                  ID = $(this).children().first().next().attr("id");
                  console.log($(this).children().first().next().html());
                  alert(ID);

                });                          
                //count = count + 1;                    
           }); 
</script>
```

I'm assuming that your actual starting HTML code is structured ok, because you wouldn't get an alert at all if that were the case. (Nothing would be found so nothing would be iterated)

---

**EDIT: As Kevin B points out in the comments, my original analysis below is flawed.  I missed the nested "each" call.**

*It may help to understand that
    $(this).children().first().next()
will retrieve the second TD tag in each table row, and none of your TD tags have an ID on them.  Hence, the undefined value for ID.
By the way, the selector you are using instructs JQuery to:
    Find #tblData, 
    then its child tbody tag, 
    then on each child tr tag, 
    find the first td tag, 
    then jump to the next one,
    then get the value of its "id" attribute
From what I can see of your html structure, I don't think that's what you really want.*

Comment: `find the first td tag, 
then jump to the next one,` that is incorrect. $(this).children().first().next() selects the children of the td, the label, and then the element after the label (which does theoretically have an id)